# Why can't I use two scanf function to enter the letters

Tags: c++, c

Why can't I use two `scanf` function to Enter the letters?

For example:

```
int a;
int b;
printf("a");
scanf("%c", &a);
printf("b");
scanf("%c", &b);
a=a+b;
printf("%c", a);
```

There are many solutions, but I want to know what is the reason why the second `scanf` function does not work.

Comment: Define "does not work". Seems to [work for me](http://rextester.com/FTN52965)

Comment: `printf(b");`  Please post valid code.

Comment: If you want to read a `char` pass a `char`.

Comment: scanf reads the ascii value.  So zero = 0x30 (48), one = 0x31 (49), two = 0x32 (50) ...  So if you enter ("1" + "1")= (49 + 49) you get the ascii character 98 which is not two

Comment: Do not significantly *change* your question after comments or answers had been given, as this might render the latter un-understandable. Add changes as addictions. I rolled back your last change therefore.

Comment: Is this `C` of `C++`?  If it's `C`, and you really didn't `#include <stdio.h>`, there are other things that are wrong, besides you not providing the correct format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is `C` not `C++` (eventhough C++ brings enough `C` compatibility to make that code valid using a conforming C++ compiler with `#include <stdio.h>`).
2. The specifier `%c` is for characters. You're reading and writing `int`.

Thus, you should use `%i`.

```
int a;
int b;
printf("a");
scanf("%i", &a);
printf("b");
scanf("%i", &b);
a=a+b;
printf("%i", a);
```

Output

```
a5
b7
12
```

Comment: This also would compile as C++, showing the same behaviour.

Comment: @alk: That's because a C++ compiler can compile some C code not because of that code being C++ code. You'd much rather use streams in C++. (And if using stdio at all I'd include `cstdio` and use `std::printf` rather than `stdio.h` and `printf`.)

Comment: If code compiles both as C++ and as C, I'd consider it C code, just because then it isn't "idiomatic C++ code".